# Check if svn repository exists

Tags: svn, connection-timeout, openwrt

I am trying to compile [this](http://luci.subsignal.org/trac/wiki/Documentation/DevelopmentEnvironmentHowTo) package, however after executing `make runuhttpd`, I get the following error:

```
svn co svn://svn.openwrt.org/openwrt/branches/backfire/package/uhttpd/src uhttpd-src
svn: Can't connect to host 'svn.openwrt.org': Connection timed out
make[1]: *** [uhttpd-src/Makefile] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/michael/Documents/openwrt/luci/trunk/contrib/uhttpd'
*** Compilation of contrib/uhttpd failed!
make: *** [gccbuild] Error 1
```

Am I doing something wrong or is `svn.openwrt.org` down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either svn.openwrt.org is down, or you cannot reach it.

Have you tried doing `svn co svn://svn.openwrt.org/openwrt/branches/backfire/package/uhttpd/src uhttpd-src` from the command line?

*Update*:
It works for me at the moment:

```
$ svn info svn://svn.openwrt.org/openwrt/branches/backfire/package/uhttpd/src
Path: src
URL: svn://svn.openwrt.org/openwrt/branches/backfire/package/uhttpd/src
Relative URL: ^/branches/backfire/package/uhttpd/src
Repository Root: svn://svn.openwrt.org/openwrt
Repository UUID: 3c298f89-4303-0410-b956-a3cf2f4a3e73
Revision: 38417
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: jow
Last Changed Rev: 30807
Last Changed Date: 2012-03-04 16:54:55 +0100 (Sun, 04 Mar 2012)
```

So either it was a temporary glitch, and works for you now as well, or you cannot access the server from your site.

Comment: aw :[, any reason why it might happen? I'm running Ubuntu inside a VM

Comment: I would guess that your routing is not setup correctly in your VM. Further is difficult to say.

Comment: Change network adapter to bridged and I get this, `svn: Can't connect to host 'svn.openwrt.org': Connection refused
`

Comment: The other option is that, for whatever reason, you have a firewall between you and the svn server that is preventing you from connecting to the svn port, which is by default 3690.